# Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid values for all parameters. (rsParameterError) sql reporting 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am using sql reporting and written query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_by = @createdby
```

and passing parameter using this code in code behind file to call this report.

```
param[0] = new ReportParameter("@createdby", "1");
       reportviewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);
```

also in rdl file. I have set this paramerter "Set Parameter visibilty" to hidden.
It is working fine where I executes this query using query builder, a define query parameter box appears and ask for query parameter. and it works great.

but while passing this parameter using .cs file. 
It gives error "Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid values for all parameters. (rsParameterError)".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per some googling on you behalf I found a possible candidate:

"Navigate to the remote report server management page  (http:///Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx).  Drill down and hover the cursor over your report, open the menu and select Manage.

On the page that opens, select Parameters and make sure the Hide box is checked for the parameter of concern.

Apply the update, and test."

Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: On drildown to report, I get this error msg "Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid values for all parameters. (rsParameterError) ". and also i want to send parameters from .aspx file containing  dropdown by send its selected value as parameter.

Comment: I'd assume you have the same error with your drill through report that you have just encountered. As for the passing of a dropdown member to a report, see here : http://forums.asp.net/t/1376774.aspx/1 .

Comment: That worked for me.  One wonders why MS simply needs to have a hide checkbox at all.

Comment: This solved my issue.  In my case I had set the "hidden" variables to Internal.  Switching them to "Hidden" worked.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue when using a query driven parameter so I could set values in a footer dynamically.

It would run fine in VS, on the report Server - manually entering param values where required, and as a subscription.

This was to be called from a 3rd party batch engine - I could set up the Selector and detail report (selector would run a query to build a list of bookings that child reports would run for) and could step through in the GUI fine, however, on processing (where the engine would also set values on the clients database post each report generated) the child report would fail with this problem, which when you have got several parameters is of no use to anybody

I threw the Reporting Server into Verbose mode (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2146315/recommended-configuration-for-verbose-logging-in-reporting-services) which then exposed which parameter was generating the error.

This parameter was data driven from a shared data source from a stored procedure. Setting the parameter to accept NULLs - even though there would be no nulls, rectified the issue (and it was set to Internal as well).

I know that this is a few years old, but it came up high in Google results so I thought I would add this for anybody else who may encounter this issue.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with a different parameter (the message is so helpful). In our case we had set a default that was not applied for another parameter that was not mentioned in the error message

We found that using the Report Builder to save parameters did not always set the correct null, blank and default value settings.

We found we had to set those on the report manager interface worked as the link between the XML and their "parameter" settings did not line up

1. Find the report starting from http://server/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ViewMode=List
2. Manage the report (right drop down arrow)
3. choose parameters
4. adjust your settings
5. Apply

We also had issues trying to set blank or null defaults

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, but none of the above solutions helped.

I deleted the report from SSRS then re-deployed it from Visual Studio.

This fixed the problem.

Comment: Note this will also delete any related elements like subscriptions that you would need to re-create

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error:

> Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid
> values for all parameters

I found this error occurred when a user had modified the report's parameter configuration from within ReportManager (to alter/add default values on parameters), and then when the report was re-uploaded with modifications to the parameters the modified parameter configuration was no longer valid, but still being used.
[image]
If you delete the report and re-upload it, this would resolve it but also delete all related data eg subscriptions that would need to be rebuilt.

To resolve more gracefully;

1. execute the following sql to clear the Parameters configuration (in `ReportServer.dbo.Catalog.Parameter`).
   *This will cause the Parameter configuration to be rebuilt to match the report being uploaded.*

```sql
   exec ReportServer.dbo.SetParameters @Path = N'/MyReportFolder/MyReport', @Parameter= NULL
```

2. Download and re-upload the report from report manager to trigger the rebuild of the parameter settings.